# Wrong height of div on iPhone 6 and 7 when using flexbox and height of 100%

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox

I have an issue on iOS iPhone 6 and 7. I'm building something like a news card. When you take a look on the content, there I'm using a `height` of `100%`. On iOS iPhone 6 and 7 it takes a wrong `height` (screenshot from browserstack):

```
.wrapper__content {
  padding: 18px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

When I remove the `height` of `100%` on the `.wrapper__content` it works:

```
.wrapper__content {
  padding: 18px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

[image]

On all browsers I tested (`Chrome`, `Firefox`, `Safari`, `Internet Explorer` and `Edge`) it works. It also works on newer iPhone like 8 or X (browserstack with same iOS and `Safari` version). Only on iPhone 6/7 (maybe also smaller, didn't test it) it seems not to work.

I can't figure out why. I tried to rebuld it in this snippet. Notice: In my project I need this `height` of `100%`. This is just an snippet example to show you the problem. The solution isn't just to remove the `height`. Any ideas why this doesn't work and how to fix it and still use `height: 100%;` for the `.wrapper__content`?

Here is also a screenshot from browserstack for iPhone X with same iOS and Safari version like the iPhone 6 and 7 and it works with the `height` of `100%`:

[image]

Here's also the codepen snippet: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/rJjVXX

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.wrapper {
  max-height: none;
  height: auto;
  width: 550px;
  box-shadow: 1px 13px 39px -5px #e2e2e2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper__image-container {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.wrapper__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper__item {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.wrapper__content {
  padding: 18px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper__content--without-height {
  padding: 18px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.wrapper__title {
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  max-height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper__text {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-height: 75px;
}

.wrapper__title,
.wrapper__text {
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.wrapper__date {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__item">
    <div class="wrapper__content">
      <h3 class="wrapper__title">Default title</h3>
      <div class="wrapper__text">Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Sed porttitor lectus nibh.</div>
      <p class="wrapper__date">08.02.2018</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper__item">
    <div class="wrapper__image-container"><img class="wrapper__image" src="http://accessasiatours.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/panda.jpg"
        alt="Testimage"></div>
    <div class="wrapper__content">
      <h3 class="wrapper__title">Default title</h3>
      <div class="wrapper__text">Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Sed porttitor lectus nibh.</div>
      <p class="wrapper__date">08.02.2018</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe the issue is caused by `flex-direction: column;` in `.wrapper__item`. Can we get rid of it?

Comment: @GibinEalias This should be the solution. I missed an important information. There are two variants of the news-cards (with and without image below text). If I remove the flex-direction column, it would solve the issue for the card without img, but then I would have trouble with that one with image. So I have to make a new class and override the flex-direction for cards without img...I updated the question take a look

Comment: Yes, hope that works for you. I will post this as an answer.

Comment: I just saw your updated question. Will try to find a solution to that scenario soon :)

Comment: Answered below. Also FYI, you can use the debug mode in codepen for a better experience. [EXAMPLE](https://s.codepen.io/gibinealias/debug/wygWjR/mVMbGEOdnVjr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to remove the `flex-direction: column;` in `.wrapper__item` as it has a bug with the `height` in older IOS versions.

Answer (score 1):

As per the updated question, we can again have a solution by excluding the `flex-direction: column;` and using the `flex-wrap: wrap;`

[PEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/wygWjR).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using viewport height instead of %? 100% would become 100vh

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp